# How to display data from database MSSQL using foreach/for loop in SQLSRV PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, for-loop, sqlsrv

I'd like to display each rows in a specific column from my db_table. Found below is the code:

```
$get_sname = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT [columnName] FROM [db_table] inner join [db_table2] on [col_fkey] = [col_pkey] WHERE userName = '$user'",array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));
$rdr_sname = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_sname, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$str = $rdr_sname['[columnName]'];
$rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($get_sname);
if($rows == false){
echo "\nerror\n";
}else{
$a = array($str);
for($i = 0;`$i < $rows;` $i++){
  foreach($a as $b){
     echo implode($a)."</br>";
  }
}
```

This loop

```
$a = array($str);
for($i = 0;$i < $rows; $i++){
    foreach($a as $b){
       echo implode($a)."</br>";
    }
}
```

returns the rows from my db in this format:

> rowName
>
> rowName
>
> rowName

what I would like it to return is something like:

> rowName1
>
> rowName2
>
> rowName3

I really appreciate all the help I can get on this. Thanks.

Comment: `</br>` isn't valid. The slash goes after the "r" and not before the "b" or none at all.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner works on both sides, either after "r" or before "b".

Comment: Oh sure they'll work, but it won't validate properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanations:**

You need to make some corrections in your code:

- Use parameterized statements to prevent SQL injections. Function `sqlsrv_query()` does both statement preparation and statement execution and can be used to execute parameterized queries.
- The code in the question fetches only the first row in the result set, because `sqlsrv_fecth_array()` is executed only once. You need to execute `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` in a loop to fetch the data from all rows.

**Example:**

You may try with the following code:

```
<?php
// Statements
$sql = "
   SELECT [columnName] 
   FROM [db_table] 
   inner join [db_table2] on [col_fkey] = [col_pkey] 
   WHERE userName = ?
";
$get_sname = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array($user), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
if ($get_sname === false){
    echo print_r( sqlsrv_errors()); 
    echo "<br>";
    exit;
}

// Results
$rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($get_sname);
if ($rows === false) {
    echo "Error"."<br>";
} else {
    while ($rdr_sname = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_sname, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
        echo $rdr_sname['columnName']."<br>";
    }
}

// End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($get_sname);  
?>
```

Comment: you are right, I needed to loop the sqlsrv_fetch_array. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29968459/11106866).

Comment: @Carl I'm glad you have a solution to your problem. Just have in mind, that it's not necessary to use two loops to output the data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

first declare the `$count` variable. like

```
$count = 0;
$a = array($str);
for($i = 0;$i < $rows; $i++){
    foreach($a as $b){
       echo implode($a).$count."</br>";
       $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually expecting for the output to display the actual [rowName] from my db. not just [rowName1], [rowName2]. My expectation is (e.g [John], [Joe], [Joseph], the code you provided returns [John1], [John2], [John3].

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody lands here looking for answers, here is the code that's fully working.

```
$get_store = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT [columnName] FROM [db_table] inner join [db_table2] on [col_fKey] = [col_pKey] where userName = '{$user}'");
if($rows == false){
  echo "\nerror\n";
  }
else{
  $sname = array();
while($storename = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_store, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    $sname[] = $storename;
}
  foreach($sname as $storename){
    echo $storename['storeName'];
}
```